# (GitHub) Can I apply a pull request from a parent project to a fork?

Tags: github, fork, pull-request

An modder submitted a pull request to an abandoned Github project; since the original developer is MIA it will never be accepted.

Is it possible to fork the abandoned project, and then somehow get the new pull request so that I can apply it to my fork?

Comment: I don't know about whether you can use the exact PR, but nothing stops you from checking out the PR's branch, and then opening a new PR on your fork.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply the PR changes toward your forked repo, assuming it's either in the `main/master` branch or in a separate branch from the other user's forked repo. You would want to change the base repository in these instructions to point to your forked copy: https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Could you give an example?

Comment: Well an example will depend on your situation. The link above should explain how to create a PR from a forked repo of one person into yours.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I know of:

1. Apply the auto-generated patch while committing with `git am < [filename].patch`, which resides at `https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/[parent repo owner]/[parent repo name]/pull/[PR number].patch`. You can also turn this into a one-liner: `curl https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/[parent repo owner]/[parent repo name]/pull/[PR number].patch | git am`.
2. Add the PR's forked repository as a remote, add its branch, and do `git merge [remotename]/[branchname]`.